# When Windows server wants to reboot to finish uninstalling a feature/role, what happens if I just never reboot?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

If I use dism or remove-windowsfeature to uninstall a windows role or feature and it tells me it needs to reboot what problems could I run into if I wait a long time to reboot?

Obviously this would vary greatly with the specific feature being uninstalled, so I'm curious if there any issues not directly related to the specific feature I should worry about- does windows installer remain in a weird unfinished state before the reboot, could this impact installing other features (features that are not related to the one uninstalled).

I know if I uninstall .net that will have an obvious impact on other features, but is there anything else in the OS, again not related to or depending on the feature I uninstall, that could go wrong?

I always reboot promptly, but I'm curious about how that reboot pending switch works and how it is registered/unregistered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I use dism or remove-windowsfeature to uninstall a windows role or feature and it tells me it needs to reboot what problems could I run into if I wait a long time to reboot?

To state the obvious, any operations that check for a pending reboot before proceeding will fail.

This includes installing many kinds of software and hotfixes.

Here is an excerpt from the website of the Sysinternals tool pendmoves:

> "There are several applications, such as service packs and hotfixes,
>   that must replace a file that's in use and is unable to. Windows
>   therefore provides the MoveFileEx API to rename or delete a file and
>   allows the caller to specify that they want the operation to take
>   place the next time the system boots, before the files are referenced.
>   Session Manager performs this task by reading the registered rename
>   and delete commands from the
>   `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations` value."

Comment: Just curious, have you seen any operations that wait for a pending reboot which aren't software installs?